# Live Tweet Maps in CartoDB

Tags: carto, twitter

This page [https://cartodb.com/cartodb-for/twitter-maps/] seems to indicate a live tweet map is possible with CartoDB, but the interface forces me to define a time span and doesn't allow me to define beyond the current date. Does anyone know how to create a Tweet map in CartoDB that will update live as new tweets meet the search criteria?

Answer (score 1):

CARTO UI does not allow to define real time twitter maps. As you correctly say they are defined once using a time span. To have near real time twitter maps you need to contact CARTO sales team as this is something custom we need to prepare on a case by case basis.